# Deleting a large number of tests from a test suite

Tags: shell, replace, scripting, editing

I have a list of about 8000 tests from which I want to remove a certain subset of tests (a whopping 432 of them) that are now passing and no longer required.

The tests entries are in the following format

```
  [img.hidden: setAttribute() to "" followed by IDL get]
    expected: FAIL

  [img.hidden: setAttribute() to " foo " followed by IDL get]
    expected: FAIL
```

The list of tests I want to remove are available to me in the following format

```
img.hidden: setAttribute() to "" followed by IDL get
img.hidden: setAttribute() to " foo " followed by IDL get
```

What would be a fast way to search and remove the entries for all these tests?

EDIT:
Example as requested. Entries:

```
  [img.hidden: IDL set to undefined followed by hasAttribute()]
    expected: FAIL

  [img.hidden: IDL set to undefined followed by IDL get]
    expected: FAIL

  [img.hidden: IDL set to null followed by hasAttribute()]
    expected: FAIL

  [img.hidden: IDL set to null followed by IDL get]
    expected: FAIL

  [img.hidden: IDL set to 7 followed by IDL get]
    expected: FAIL
```

Removal list:

```
img.hidden: IDL set to undefined followed by IDL get
img.hidden: IDL set to null followed by IDL get
img.hidden: IDL set to 7 followed by IDL get
```

Expected output:

```
  [img.hidden: IDL set to undefined followed by hasAttribute()]
    expected: FAIL

  [img.hidden: IDL set to null followed by hasAttribute()]
    expected: FAIL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed` as

```
while read pattern
do 
sed -i "/$pattern/, +1 d" inputFile
done < test
```

**Test**

```
$ cat input
[img.hidden: IDL set to undefined followed by hasAttribute()]
    expected: FAIL

[img.hidden: IDL set to undefined followed by IDL get]
    expected: FAIL

[img.hidden: IDL set to null followed by hasAttribute()]
    expected: FAIL

[img.hidden: IDL set to null followed by IDL get]
    expected: FAIL

[img.hidden: IDL set to 7 followed by IDL get]
    expected: FAIL

$ cat test
img.hidden: IDL set to undefined followed by IDL get
img.hidden: IDL set to null followed by IDL get
img.hidden: IDL set to 7 followed by IDL get

$ while read pattern; do sed -i "/$pattern/, +1 d" input ; done < test

$ cat input
[img.hidden: IDL set to undefined followed by hasAttribute()]
    expected: FAIL


[img.hidden: IDL set to null followed by hasAttribute()]
    expected: FAIL
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working, oddly enough, it turns my input file into 8000 blank lines

Comment: Added an example to the question.

Comment: Turns out changing the pattern from `"/$pattern/, +1 d"` to `"/$pattern/,+1d"` does the trick. Wonder why...? Also it should be `+2d` instead, to remove blank lines following each test.

Comment: @aakashjain space must not make difference. Tried both and works fine. +2 will remove 2 line. +1 may be safer for cases where there is no blank line after the test case

Comment: @aakashjain Anyways glad to hear it helped :)